# how to pass arguments from one gui to other gui?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am working on matlab gui. I have to call another gui on clicking a button in current gui. But i have to pass some values like a image and a text string from current gui to the new gui. How can i do this. I have simply open the new gui without passing any information.

```
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton8 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
warning off;
choice = questdlg('Would you really want to goto next window ?', ...
    'RESET Dialog', ...
    'YES','NO','');

switch choice
    case 'YES'
        clc;clear all;close all;subpart;
    case 'NO'

end
```

Comment: One way would be using `global variables`.

Comment: You can use `gcbf` to refer to the current figure.

Comment: subpart is another gui and i have to pass arguments to that gui from current gui. How can i retrieve these arguments in subpart.

Comment: A possibility is: Call `subpart` from current figure before closing current figure. From new figure you can retrieve arguments from current figure using `gcbf`. Then close current figure from new figure

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you pass the all the data you want through a struct called myData that is stored inside handles. Then you'd have to simply call

```
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton8 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
warning off;
choice = questdlg('Would you really want to goto next window ?', ...
    'RESET Dialog', ...
    'YES','NO','');

switch choice
    case 'YES'
        mySecondGUI(handles.myData);
        delete(hObject);
    case 'NO'

end
```

This way your second gui recieves the information. The second thing you have to do is modifying your Openingfunction in your second gui:

```
mySecondGUID_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

handles.theDataFromFirstGUI = varargin{1};

% ... Any initialisationstuff

guidata(hObject,handles);
```

In case you encounter problems with the old gui not properly closing I suggest you to read the articles regarding uiwait and uiresume: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html

I hope this helps, cheers Pablo